# Is it possible to resubmit a corrected manuscript when the manuscript is under review?

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, journal-workflow

About 10 days ago, I submitted a revised manuscript based on the comments of Referee. But I just found out that I made a mistake in the newly added appendix. Now, the revised manuscript is under review, and I am not sure if the Referee is reading it or not.

So I want to know if it is appropriate to submit a new manuscript with the mistake corrected.

It is the first time I encountered this embarrassing situation. I should have been more careful.

Comment: If the mistake is minor, do nothing.

Comment: Depending on the severity of the error, see either https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44466/a-trivial-correction-to-my-currently-under-review-paper-what-to-do?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20098/i-found-a-nontrivial-mistake-in-my-currently-under-review-paper-should-i-send-a.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this**. If you submit your manuscript as a new one it'll be treated as a new one, which means things such as editorial review and plagiarism checks need to be done again. It's possible the system will detect the duplicate submission, but if it isn't there's no guarantee it'll be noticed quickly simply because you might not be assigned to the same editor.

Instead, email the journal office and tell them what you've written in the question. They can halt the review process and return the manuscript to you for revision.

Comment: Editorial management systems usually prompt the submitter to indicate that the manuscript is a revision.  If that is filled out, your concerns will not be relevant.